# Is there any way to transpose a HTML table using VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have a macro allows me send emails of monthly performance to each manager. Codes are as follow:

```
Sub OutlookEmailsSend()
    
    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim lCounter As Long
    Dim endColumnNo As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim sFile As String
    
    endColumnNo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count
    
    Set objOutlook = Outlook.Application
   
    For lCounter = 2 To 3
        '
        Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        
        objMail.To = Sheet1.Range("B" & lCounter).Value
              
        objMail.Subject = "Sales Summary"
        
        sFile = "Dear,<br><br>Please refer to below table for your performance<br><br><table border=1>"
        
        For a = 1 To endColumnNo
            sFile = sFile & "<tr><td>" & Cells(1, a) & "</td><td>" & Cells(lCounter, a) & "</td></tr>"
        Next
        
        objMail.HTMLBody = sFile
        
        objMail.Display
       
        Set objMail = Nothing
    Next
    
End Sub
```

The macro produce table like this

```
Dear,

Please refer to below table for your performance

Name    Tom
Email   sgcjack@163.com
Item    Phone
Sales   123
Bonus   3213
```

However, I would like the table presents as follow

```
Name    Email                   Item     Sales  Bonus
Jack    jacksun@citics.com.hk   Computer 342    23123
```

Is there any way can do this?

Comment: simply, the `<tr>` tag goes outside the loop. You are now creating a row for each field. Add `<tr>` after `<table>` tag

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table4

Comment: @LelioFaieta Hi, Thanks for the answer, I changed my code to `sFile = "<table border=1><tr>"      
For a = 1 To endColumnNo
sFile = sFile & "<td>" & Cells(lCounter, a) & "</td>"  Next objMail.HTMLBody = sFile & "</tr></table>"` and this time the table was successfully transposed but I did this by ignoring the header, do I have to add another loop like `sFile1` to include the header?

Comment: @LelioFaieta  the final result is shown as `Jack    jacksun@163.com   Computer 342    23123`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of better readibility it might be helpful to organize the html creation in a function and to assign the function result to `objMail.HTMLBody` omitting the loops.

*Btw you forgot the closing table tag `</table>` which wouldn't result in a valid html structure. - Of course, the most direct approach following the original code would be to follow the recommendation in comment to add the `<tr>..</tr>` tags outside the loop not forgetting the closing `</table>` tag.*

```
    With Sheet1
        objMail.HTMLBody = getBody(.Range("A1",.Cells(1,EndColumnNo)),"Dear xx")`
    End With
```

The **help function `getBody()`** joins (a) headers and (b) table data based on a (c) clearly defined table structure.

*Note: You can play around and change that definition to a more sophisticated html code with separate header tags, too.*.

```
Function getBody(rng    As Range, _
    Optional greetings  As String = "", _
    Optional HeaderList As String = "Name,Email,Item,Sales,Bonus")
Const Blanks As String = "  "
'a) get headers
    Dim headers As String
    headers = "  <td>" & Replace(HeaderList, ",", "</td><td>") & "</td>"
'b) join table data "<td>..</td>"
    Dim data As String
    data = Blanks & _
        Join(rng.Parent.Evaluate("""<td>""&" & rng.Address(0, 0) & " & ""</td>""") _
        , vbNewLine & Blanks)
'c) define table structure
    Dim tags()
    tags = Array(greetings, _
        "<table border='1'>", _
        " <tr>", headers, " </tr>", _
        " <tr>", data, " </tr>", _
        "</table>")
'd) return joined function result
    getBody = Join(tags, vbNewLine)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! do I have to change Headlist if header names changed? Also I try to change `<tr>..</tr>` outside the loop like `sFile = "<table border=1><tr>"
For a = 1 To endColumnNo
sFile = sFile & "<td>" & Cells(lCounter, a) & "</td>"
Next
objMail.HTMLBody = sFile & "</tr></table>"` it can transpose without headers `Jack    jacksun@163.com   Computer 342    23123` but if I try to add headers the table just got mess how can I add a transposed header as well?

Comment: You are welcome. Of course you'd have to either a) change the default headlist argument in the function to another comma separated list or b) to call the function with a third string argument like e.g. `objMail.HTMLBody = getBody(.Range("A1",.Cells(1,EndColumnNo)),"Dear xx","Col1,Col2,Col3,....etc")`.  @SunGuochen

Comment: Though unrelated to the original post, I'll try to answer your additional question: it will be necessary to add a separate loop to get all header information, too with a closing </tr> after the first loop and a starting <tr> before the second data loop. If you have issues it would be helpful to edit where to find the actual header information.